# Vcard photo not appearing on contacts

Tags: image, url, vcf-vcard

I have made up a NFC chip with a Vcard on it.   Everything works but the image.   Can anybody help?

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N:Coral'sVinylTees;;;
FN:Coral
EMAIL;HOME:coralsvinyltees@gmail.com
ORG:Coral's Vinyl Tees
TITLE:Coral
URL:www.coralsvinyltees.com
URL:www.facebook.com/coralsvinyltees
URL:www.instagram.com/coralsvinyltees
PHOTO;TYPE=JPEG;VALUE=URL:https://www.coralsvinyltees.com/images/spraylogocrop.png

END:VCARD
```

Comment: A little late, but did you found a solution? I've got a similar problem and it seems only jpg files do work - png does not.

Answer (score 1):

To solve your problem, you need to include a base64 encoded image URI like so:

```
PHOTO;ENCODING=BASE64;TYPE=GIF:R0lGODdhYABgAPAAALccHMlFJiH5BAEAAAEALAAAAABgAGAAAAJuhI+py+0Po5y02ouz3rz7D4biSJbmiabqyrbuC8fyTNf2jef6zvf+DwwKh8Si8YhMKpfMpvMJjUqn1Kr1is1qt9yu9wsOi8fksvmMTqvX7Lb7DY/L5/S6/Y7P6/f8vv8PGCg4SFhoeIiYqLiIUgAAOw==
```

If you include the above line in your code, you will realize the default image is changed to a red background... So a BASE64 Encoding works.